# ngTagsInput - Set onTagAdding callback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

I'm trying to set a default function for the `onTagAdding` callback using the `tagsInputConfig` provider. No success.

```
tagsInputConfig.setDefaults('tagsInput', {
    placeholder: 'Search',
    maxTags: 10,
    minLength: 5,
    maxLength: 40,
    replaceSpacesWithDashes: false,
    onTagAdding: function (x,y,z) {
        debugger; // breakpoint is never called
    }
});
```

All the other default options are set correctly, except for the callBacks. In the other hand, it works when I configure it as a property:

```
<tags-input on-tag-adding="onTagAdding($tag)" ng-model="search"></tags-input>
```

Is there any way to set a default function for this callback?

Comment: Are you calling this from your `.config` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I can tell from the [documentation (tags-input.js && configuration.js)](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/d70f00ad09154b6216fcdc5c30752d77fca5ac47/src/tags-input.js) it appears that onTagAdding is not a default that you can specify.

Per the source, here is the complete list that is available directly from the source code (*PS: the keys for the object in the fourth argument are the names of the defaults*):

```
tagsInputConfig.load('tagsInput', $scope, $attrs, {
                template: [String, 'ngTagsInput/tag-item.html'],
                type: [String, 'text', validateType],
                placeholder: [String, 'Add a tag'],
                tabindex: [Number, null],
                removeTagSymbol: [String, String.fromCharCode(215)],
                replaceSpacesWithDashes: [Boolean, true],
                minLength: [Number, 3],
                maxLength: [Number, MAX_SAFE_INTEGER],
                addOnEnter: [Boolean, true],
                addOnSpace: [Boolean, false],
                addOnComma: [Boolean, true],
                addOnBlur: [Boolean, true],
                addOnPaste: [Boolean, false],
                pasteSplitPattern: [RegExp, /,/],
                allowedTagsPattern: [RegExp, /.+/],
                enableEditingLastTag: [Boolean, false],
                minTags: [Number, 0],
                maxTags: [Number, MAX_SAFE_INTEGER],
                displayProperty: [String, 'text'],
                keyProperty: [String, ''],
                allowLeftoverText: [Boolean, false],
                addFromAutocompleteOnly: [Boolean, false],
                spellcheck: [Boolean, true]
            });
```

### tl;dr

#### No you can't set a default function for the onTagAdding callback, but it could be a great issue to submit on their [github](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/issues)!!!

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can define any function from your scope to be the callback, here's an example

```
# test.html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <tags-input on-tag-adding="myFunction($tag)" ng-model="search"></tags-input>
</div>
```

And in js file

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = function($tag) {
        console.log($tag);
        return false;
    };
});
```

Hope it helps!